# Using a friend to move cash into my checking account

Tags: cash

I have a few thousand dollars that I want to move into my checking account, but as I pointed out in my previous question my bank does not have local branches or ATM partners.

I have a friend who will take the cash and deposit it in their account, then write me a check that I can deposit with my bank's app.  I trust this person completely.

Is there any danger in doing this (such as potential tax issues)?

Comment: The only risk is if you think he’s a friend but he isn’t. Don’t do that with people you know only online or for a short time.

Comment: Banks have limits on how large a check can be when depositing via the app. Usually it is a few thousand dollars.

Comment: In my mobile deposit experience, payroll checks go through quite quickly - But personal checks can take up to 4 days.

Comment: Why not just open a second bank account with a bank which accepts cash and pay it in there?

Comment: How do you normally make deposits into this account?

Comment: Why would you not just pay a few dollars for a postal money order, or for western union to send it to your bank account?

Comment: If the amount is no more than a few thousand. Go to a local convenience store and buy money orders and deposit them to your account with a mobile deposit. I did this a few times before I just opened up a bank account with a bank that has lots of branches and keep the minimum balance in there to avoid fees.

Comment: Different countries may have different rules.

Comment: What happened when you called USAA customer service and asked them what they suggested?

Comment: As @Harper-ReinstateMonica asked, what did USAA say? They have an excellent reputation (especially for a bank), so I'm curious what they have to say directly. I would be stupefied if they didn't have a stock answer ready, or some suggestion.  There's no way you're the first who needs to do this type of thing.

Comment: @Travis: Money orders are on the "not eligible for mobile deposit" list in terms and conditions of many banks, at least for consumer accounts.

Comment: @BenVoigt According to a couple of search results ([here](https://www.wikihow.com/Deposit-Cash-with-USAA) and [here](https://twitter.com/usaa/status/1241174521647792128?lang=en)), you _can_ deposit Money Orders with the USAA mobile app.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**No there are no tax issues or anything similar.**

You are moving money that you have from one account to another. Your friend is acting as your agent and gains no income or expenditure from the transactions. Neither will trigger any tax concerns. In fact the IRS will not even know about the transactions unless they decide to audit you or your friend. (If the amount is over $10,000 you will have to go through anti money laundering forms.)

Other than the possibility of you friend not being as trustworthy as you think I see no problems.

Comment: Note that multiple deposits of just under $10,000 would be even worse than just making one deposit and filling out the forms, because that shows that you're trying to hide it.

Comment: @nick012000: Yes, that's very important to emphasize. If the total amount is over $10k, you should fill out the relevant forms and/or directly inform the authorities, just to make sure that you don't get flagged for structuring. Also, make sure you have a completely airtight explanation of where the money came from (e.g. "It came from my paycheck, here are all of the applicable bank statements, W-2s, etc. showing the relevant deposits and withdrawals").

Comment: Why would this not cause a problem for the friend? They would suddenly have a few thousand dollars of income. As far as the bank or the IRS is concerned, they would just see a large deposit being made, and then removed, possibly to fund a purchase. Is there some system in the US by which as long as the money is removed within a certain time limit, it doesn't need to be declared or something?

Comment: @terdon It's not a problem because the action itself isn't a problem to begin with. We're not assuming it is an attempt at actual money laundering. You're basically asking "How can IRS tell this isn't money laundering?" Well, because it actually isn't! There is no expense by the friend. If the IRS actually investigates, OP can readily show the deposit and that will be it.

Comment: @Nelson no, I am saying "Why would the IRS not see this as undeclared income for the friend?". I understand that if an audit were to occur, they could explain this away, but that doesn't mean it wouldn't trigger an audit, right? The answer seems to claim that this could never cause any issues, not that any issues could eventually be resolved, and I am wondering why that would be the case.

Comment: Having an IRS audit isn't a problem in and of itself. Are you saying it somehow is? Besides, this is tangential and should be a separate question.

Comment: How is an IRS audit not a problem? It takes time to respond, and if the person audited engages a professional to assist, which is a reasonable thing to do, money.

Comment: @terdon: The reason it isn't an issue is that making a deposit is not income, and is not even reported to the IRS.

Comment: The IRS would only know about this if it was already doing an audit, from my understanding.  They're not looking at every $5000 deposit everyone makes, or even $15000 unless there are other relevant factors.

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you. That's what I was missing since I am used to tax systems where deposits are very much made available to the local equivalent of the IRS so receiving several thousands dollars into an account could be a red flag if that is not declared as income.

Comment: @terdon: There's a pretty big kerfluffle over a proposal to start reporting: https://www.cbsnews.com/news/irs-bank-account-update-change-treasury-10000-dollars/.  But deposits are still not income.  People regularly move tens of thousands of dollars between banking accounts and brokerage accounts.  Capital gains are reported and taxed.  Mere transfers are neither taxable nor (so far) reportable.

Comment: I just discussed this with a friend who's been dealing with an accountant and it sounds like this would very likely lead to an audit. Sure, maybe you can explain it away, but I really feel that your absolute, blanket "No there are no tax issues" is misleading. I don't know the details of the US tax system, but I do know there are ways for the IRS to be made aware of undeclared funds (e.g. a foreign bank account whose contents are reported by the foreign state, a normal occurrence for US citizens with money abroad), so unless you can provide some references I fear your answer may be misleading.

Comment: I believe that even if there was an audit and the IRS examined this very carefully they would still find nothing wrong, nor require you to pay any taxes because of these transactions. Can your friend point to what about this might cause tax to be payable?

Comment: @DJClayworth the problem _is_ the IRS audit. That is a complex, long, and unpleasant process even if everything turns out absolutely fine.

Comment: How will the IRS know the OP has done this?

Answer (score 11):

There are no ***LEGAL*** issues really (assuming you're in the U.S., of course), although when you say "a few thousand" dollars, you might be careful that your friend might have to answer some questions with his/her bank if the amount goes over $10,000, at which point the bank is required to report the transaction, both for tax and Homeland Security reasons.